# Slidein element is visible before the animation

Tags: javascript, animation, velocity.js

I'm trying to recreate the animations when loading from this website:
https://uchuhimo.me

I think they are using velocity.js to do the animations.

I tried to recreate some of this and kind of succeeded (though not sure if doing it properly). There is one problem though, that the elements are there and then they animate (slidein), whereas correctly they should be hidden and then they slide in so they become visible (like on the website). I looked into documentation and i think that should be expected behaviour? But here in my example it does not work like that.

https://codepen.io/pokepim/pen/EpyKWR

The sequence of animation I run is the following:
And they should imitate the animation of that website im trying to imitate.

```
var loading = [
     { elements: $(".logo-line-before"), properties: {width: '100%'}},
     { elements: $(".logo-line-after"), properties: {width: '100%'}, options: { sequenceQueue: false }},
     { elements: $(".ttl"), properties:"transition.slideDownIn"},
     { elements: $(".ui.top.vertical.segment"), properties:"transition.slideDownBigIn"}
]; 

$.Velocity.RunSequence(loading);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's all using Velocity V1 so there's limited help available (it's not supported any more), however you do need to pre-load the elements for `opacity:0`, there's no need for changing the `display` property on them as it's just a "get it visible" animation on an element that should still take up space.

I'd suggest simply adding a `style="opacity:0;"` on each of those elements in the HTML source and going from there.

Comment: Oh thanks, that actually worked. I will try to use the newever verion of velocity but i had some issues with compatibility so need to check that. But there is still one thing that looks a bit bothersome, when those both black lines are animating then there is noticeable expansion of the element between them. I tried bigger margins on that element `ttl` but it does not work. https://codepen.io/pokepim/pen/EpyKWR